# glib2 build can't find automake 1.13 when automake 1.14 is installed

Tags: centos, glib, automake

I'm attempting to build glib-2.36.4 on CentOS5.  I realize it would be wiser to upgrade to 6 but this isn't possible because of a customer requirement.

I've started a make build and I get the below error.  The error complains that automake-1.13 doesn't exist on the system.   However,  I built automake 1.14 and installed it.  An automake --version outputs the correct version.

I've done a yum list installed | grep automake to insure automake doesn't have conflicting installations.

I've tried googling the issue but I can't come up with anything.

---

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/tharper/glib-2.36.4/docs/reference/glib'
 cd ../../.. && /bin/sh /home/tharper/glib-2.36.4/missing
automake-1.13 --gnu docs/reference/glib/Makefile
/home/tharper/glib-2.36.4/missing: line 81: automake-1.13: command not found
WARNING: 'automake-1.13' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make[4]: *** [Makefile.in] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/tharper/glib-2.36.4/docs/reference/glib'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/tharper/glib-2.36.4/docs/reference'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/tharper/glib-2.36.4/docs'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tharper/glib-2.36.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the top level directory run the command

```
automake
```

Basically, your makefiles were built using Automake 1.13 and now you've got 1.14 they're getting confused, so running automake will recreate all the Makefiles using your new version.

Comment: I ran automake, then configure and then make.  I still have the same issue.

Comment: Did you run the aclocal command in that directory, then automake, then make?  That worked for me, for a similar problem.

Comment: I've abandoned this attempt.  The customer changed their requirement and this is no longer necessary.  Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 9):

In my side, it will show some warning after run automake, and I run the command to resolved this issue:
 autoreconf -ivf

Answer (score 7):

I ran in a similar problem when trying to compile gnome-mplayer-1.0.9.2 on Ubuntu 14.01.1.

I managed to resolve it by running the following commands in the source folder:

```
aclocal
automake
./configure
make
```